# Unable to record simple HP flight application script using LoadRunner

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I am recording the scripts for sample HP application using LoadRunner 12.02 but after recording the script, no script is getting generated in Vugen and in the log can see following details:

```
****** Start Log Message ******
Web Recorder version : 12.0.2739.0 
Recording Mode: HTML-based script
Not recording headers
Not excluding content types
Do not record this content types as a resource:
  text/html
  text/xml
Reset context between actions
Record non-HTML elements in current HTML function
Protocol Type: Multi-QTWeb
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: try with protocol Web(HTTP/HTML). "Do not record this content types as a resource: text/html text/xml", remove text/html and try. I suggest trying with different browser also.

Comment: detailed documentation available here http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/Tutorial/Recording.htm

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using **Web(HTTP/HTML)** protocol during recording.

Follow the detailed steps mentioned Load Runner Documentation for HP flight booking (WebTours) java-based application (LR 12.53 community edition):

[Offcial Tutorial for WebTours and Load Runner basics](http://lrhelp.saas.hp.com/en/latest/help/WebHelp/Content/Tutorial/WebTours.htm)